# Mirror Data Between Two TCP Streams - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, networking, proxy

I've been working on creating a transparent proxy application in vb.net for a few days now. All was going great until now.. I'm having trouble finding the best way to mirror the data from the client to the server and vise-versa.

I've tried multiple different methods. Here's my latest. It works the best so far, but the page never finishes loading.

```
Do Until NeedToClose = True

                    If client.Connected = True Then
                        If client.GetStream.DataAvailable = True Then
                            Dim buffer(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                            Dim length As Integer
                            Try
                                length = client.GetStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) 'fills buffer with request
                                server.GetStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                            Catch ex As Exception

                            End Try
                        End If

                        If server.Connected = False Then
                            'client is holding connection open. server has already disconnected
                            stopWorker()
                        End If

                        If server.Connected = True Then
                            If server.GetStream.DataAvailable = True Then
                                Dim buffer(server.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                                Dim length As Integer
                                Try
                                    length = server.GetStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) 'fills buffer with request
                                    client.GetStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try
                            End If

                            If client.Connected = False Then
                                'server is holding connection open. client has already disconnected
                                stopWorker()
                            End If
                        End If


                    End If

                    If client.Connected = False And server.Connected = False Then
                        stopWorker()
                    End If
                Loop
```

Probably not the best way to accomplish this. The Try..Catch's are just there for a breakpoint to sit on. I've already received the connection from the client, pulled out the Host attribute, and connected to the server. Then, I sent the first request that I got from the client to the server. Then, the code you see above kicks in and starts relaying requests and replies.

**Is there a better way to do this? And why doesn't the page ever load fully?**
Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the code I posted above works perfectly well. I traced the problem back to some poor multithreading in other parts of my program. Once I fixed that, pages started loading.

I'm still curious. Is there an even better or faster way of passing data between two streams?